# why shell logical not in if condition test behave not as expected

Tags: linux, shell

in my shell:

```
if ! mycommand;then
  echo "mycommand has 0 exit code"
else
  echo "mycommand has non-zero exit code"
fi
```

why *mycommand* return 1 but echo "mycommand has 0 exit code"?

I changed code as following:

```
mycommand
ret=$?
if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "mycommand has 0 exit code"
else
  echo "mycommand has non-zero exit code"
fi
```

when *mycommand* return 1,echo "mycommand has non-zero exit code" as i expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if`-block will be executed only if the test condition returns 0, meaning success.  A nonzero value will be considered an error and the `else`-block will be executed.

```
if something; then
    echo "Command succeeded (exit code 0)"
else
    echo "Command failed (exit code $?)"
fi
```

So remove the `!` in your first code block and you will get the desired behavior.

Further reading: [Bash Guide for Beginners: Conditional statements](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_07.html)

Answer (score 0):

In bash 0 means true, and any higher means false. So the negative `! mycommand` became true, when `mycommand` is false.

Answer (score 0):

In shell if the executed command is correct it return 0 which store in $?. If we execute wrong command it return non-zero(1-255) value which also store in $?.

```
 Exit Value     Exit Status
 0 (Zero)   Success
 Non-zero   Failure
 1          False
 2          Incorrect usage
 127        Command Not found
 126        Not an executable
```